# Ajax ignores html validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, required

```
$('#addProduct').click(function (e) {
        $('#qty').attr('required', 'required');
        $('#product_id').attr('required', 'required');
        e.preventDefault();

var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
        var data = $("#editOrderContent").serializeArray();
        data.push(addProduct);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: $('#editOrderContent').attr('action'),
        data: data,

        success: function (html) {
            if (html.error) {
                $('.wrap_result')
                    .text(html.error)
                    .fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
            }
            else if (html.success) {
                $('#summary').before(html.tdProduct);
                $('#summary_qty').text(html.summaries['qty']);
                $('#summary_price').text(html.summaries['price'] + ' $.');
                $('#summary_sum').text(html.summaries['sum'] + ' $.');
                $('#product_id').val('');
                $('#qty').val(1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

These 2 fields has required attributes but ajax still completing even with empty values in these fields, also ajax ignores min value of #qty field

Why is this happening?

Comment: That's not all your code - show enough so we can understand what you're trying to do

Comment: This code doesn't check for validity, but puts the `required` attr to those elements.

Comment: @BatMannn what you are doing is completely weird why you bind validations on click rather than in `document.ready` it would be better to bind all validation rules on page load  for more info i have provided a link where you can find a demo

Comment: @Curiousdev because I have second button Remove in which I need to remove validations

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#formid').valid()` method before making ajax request read more about [.valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

Comment: Where does it say the user is using the jQuery validation plug-in?

Comment: Ohhh that's a  good one but he didn't say he is not using even no worries you could be right but i have provide a link as well in case of he wants to use what he does is simply weird and aforementioned link provided a full demo example

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault tells the event NOT to perform it's default action of submitting the form.

You're then making the fields required. That's fine - but they'll only be checked on submit. The form isn't actually being submitted at any point, you've told it to prevent that action.

You need to add a $('#form').submit(); Or add required directly to the html markup.

EDIT: Much more code added to the question. This may no longer apply.